# ImageMapster - Limit selections on an image map

Tags: jquery, limit, imagemapster

I'm using the ImageMapster jQuery plugin, and I want to limit the number of selections that can be made on a (image-) map to a certain number.

Let's say I have 30 areas, but only want 3 to be selected at the same time. After 3 selections have been made, the 4th selection should overwrite the 3rd.

Is there a way I can do this? Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Sry, I have missed an issue on GitHub, which does exactly what I was looking for.

https://github.com/jamietre/ImageMapster/pull/179

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue on GitHub taking care of this, and extending the orginal functionality of ImageMapster.

https://github.com/jamietre/ImageMapster/pull/179